# First Order Nonlinear PDE - Discrete Ray Method

Tags: partial-differential-equations, asymptotics, systems-of-equations, inverse-function, parametrization

In the application of the discrete ray method to the mixed differential-difference equation below , as $n \to \infty $:

$G'_n(x) = e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2\,n\,(n+1)}}\,G_{n-1}(x)$, $G_{0}(x)=1$

and setting $G_{n}(x) = \epsilon^{-n}\,\phi(\epsilon\,x,\epsilon\,n)$, one obtains the following differential equation:

$\epsilon\,\frac{\partial \phi(u,v)}{\partial\,u} = e^{-\frac{u^{2}}{2\,v(v+\epsilon)}}\,\phi(u,v-\epsilon)$; $u = \epsilon\;x, v = \epsilon\;n, n \in \mathbb{N}^{+}, \epsilon\ \to 0$

At this point the following ansatz is inserted into the pde above:

$\phi(u,v)\sim \exp(\epsilon^{-1}\psi(u,v))K(u,v)$

Expanding both sides, in a Taylor series $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^{2})$ around $\epsilon=0$, and comparing like terms of $\epsilon$, two equations will emerge. The first is discussed here.

**Eikonal Equation**

$F(u,v,\psi,p,q) = \ln(p)$ + $\frac{u^{2}}{2\:v^{2}}+q=0$
; where p = $\frac{\partial\psi(u,v)}{\partial u}$, q = $\frac{\partial\psi(u,v)}{\partial v}$

The method of characteristics applied to the above -

$\{ \frac{d\,u}{d\,t}= \frac{1}{p}, \frac{d\,v}{d\,t}=1,\frac{d\,p}{d\,t}=-\frac{u^{2}}{v^{2}}, \frac{d\,q}{d\,t}=\frac{u^{2}}{v^{3}},\frac{d\,\psi}{d\,t}=q+1 
\}$

with the following initial conditions

$u(s,0)=0,v(s,0)=s,p(s,0)=1,q(s,0)=0,\psi(s,0)=0$

Upon setting $\beta=erf^{-1}(a\:\frac{v-\alpha s}{s})$ and solving for $p$ first, which is an Emden-Fowler type equation, we obtain:

$u(s,t)=\sqrt{e}\:s\:\exp(-\beta^{2})+\sqrt{2}\:v\:\beta \\
v(s,t)=s+t \\
p(s,t)=\frac{\sqrt{e}\;s}{v}\exp(-\beta^{2}) \\
q(s,t)=\ln(\frac{v}{s})+\beta^{2}-\frac{u^{2}}{2\;v^{2}}-\frac{1}{2} \\
\psi(s,t)=v\;(\ln(\frac{v}{s}-\frac{1}{2}))+\frac{e\;s^{2}}{2\;v}\exp(-2\;\beta^{2})
$

With:
$a=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi\;e}}$, $\alpha =\sqrt{\frac{\pi\;e}{2}}\;erf(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})+1$

(u,v) $\in \mathbb{R}^{+}\times\mathbb{R}^{+} $, $v\neq 0$

Any help or suggestions in finding t(u,v) e.g. a series expansion, a uniform expansion, etc. would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Andre

Comment: **Welcome** to the site ! As you wrote it : *almost*. There is no explicit solution; think about numerical methods.

Comment: Hello Claude - thank you for your response. I don't want to resort to numerical methods, what I would like is a uniform expansion. This problem is actually more complicated than stated - it is actually a system of two equations where u and theta are functions of (s,t). I have tried reversion of series and Pade approximants.

Comment: Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Good to know that ! I am a fanatic lover of Taylor and Padé. With Padé approximants, we can do a lot of very nice things. Is it impossible to elminate one of the variables (say $u$) and have a single equation in $\theta$. At this point, series reversion or Padé approximants could be giving ... something ! Cheers :-)

Comment: Can you say something about the variables,please?

Comment: All real variables and the constraint from the inverse error function: -1 < a (v- b s)/ s < 1

Comment: What is the connection to inverse problems?

Comment: none, my mistake.